# Magento: observer file

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento not use extends in some **observer.php file in created module?**

Comment: Because there's nothing to extend. There is not such a thing as a 'general observer' which has some predefined functionality. You have to be more precise if your question is about some particular file you found.

Comment: You should add that as an answer @MarkvanderSanden.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I think you're right! I thought the question was so broad that there couldn't be a real answer :)

Comment: @MarkvanderSanden I was somewhere between "this is too broad" and "there won't be another answer than yours" :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there's nothing to extend. There is not such a thing as a 'general observer' which has some predefined functionality. Please be more precise if your question is about some particular file you found.